# Accessing the Recycle Bin

Tags: vb.net

I would like to examine the files in the recycle bin as if it were a normal directory, specifically get the list of files there and the date each file arrived in the recycle bin.

Answer (score 5):

this code helps you

```
'Access the recycle bin folder  
    Dim SH As New Shell32.Shell  
    Dim RecycleBin As Shell32.Folder = SH.NameSpace(Shell32.ShellSpecialFolderConstants.ssfBITBUCKET)  

    Dim SB As New StringBuilder  
    'Loop through the Recycle Bin and get each Items Name  
    For Each Item As Shell32.FolderItem In RecycleBin.Items  
        SB.AppendLine(Item.Name)  
    Next Item  

    'Display the list of filenames in a label  
    Label1.Text = SB.ToString
```

Comment: Amazing! Did not know it's that easy. +1

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something, but I cannot find the date the file arrived in the recycle bin...

Comment: I have the same issue, someone knows the solution?