# How to Invoke a Verb on a ShellFile/ShellFolder/ShellObject objects using Windows API Code Pack?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, recycle-bin, windows-api-code-pack

I'm looking for a `C#` or `Vb.NET` solution to know how I can invoke the `undelete` verb on a `ShellObject` (`ShellFile` or `ShellFolder`) stored in the recycle bin.

The recycle bin part I've it written, what I only need is to know how to invoke a verb on a deleted item.

To understand me better I'll show this example of how I invoke a verb using the `Shell32` Interface, but I can't find any similar method on the `ShellObject/ShellFile/ShellFolder` items of the `Windows API Code Pack` library where I'm interested to use:

```
Private SH As New Shell
Private RecycleBin As Folder = 
        SH.NameSpace(ShellSpecialFolderConstants.ssfBITBUCKET)

Dim RandomDeletedItem As FolderItem = RecycleBin.Items.Cast(Of FolderItem)(1)

RandomDeletedItem.InvokeVerb("undelete")
```

And this should be the `Windows API Code Pack` incompleted equivalent (In `VB.NET`)

```
Private Shared RecycleBin As IKnownFolder = KnownFolders.RecycleBin

Dim RandomDeletedItem As ShellObject = RecycleBin(1)
Dim RandomDeletedFile As ShellFile = RecycleBin(1)
Dim RandomDeletedFolder As ShellFolder = RecycleBin(1)

' Here I need to know how to invoke the "undelete" verb on each object above...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use ShellExecuteEx to undelete a file in the Recycling Bin given its parsing name:

```
    ' some file we got from the recycle bin iterating through the IShellItems:
    Dim sParsing As String = _
      "E:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-2546332361-822210090-45395533-1001\$RTD2G1Z.PNG"
    Dim shex As New SHELLEXECUTEINFO
    shex.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(shex)

    ' Here we want ONLY the file name.
    shex.lpFile = Path.GetFileName(sParsing)

    ' Here we want the exact directory from the parsing name
    shex.lpDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(sParsing)
    shex.nShow = SW_SHOW  ' = 5
    '' here the verb is undelete, not restore.
    shex.lpVerb = "undelete"

    ShellExecuteEx(shex)
```

Comment: please could you provide the reference documentation to SW_NORMAL with the other constants? I need to know their values to test it

Comment: Honestly I think that parameter could be anything.

Comment: actually that should be SW_SHOW, not SW_NORMAL.

Answer (score 6):

Here is some utility code that allows you to call any verb on any shell item. This is a small sample on the `Recycle Bin` folder and the `undelete` canonical verb:

```
IKnownFolder folder = KnownFolders.RecycleBin;
foreach (ShellObject deleted in folder)
{
    if (...) // whatever
    {
        CallShellItemVerb(deleted.Properties.System.ParsingPath.Value, "undelete");
    }
}

public static void CallShellItemVerb(string parsingPath, string verb)
{
    if (parsingPath == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parsingPath");

    if (verb == null)
    {
        verb = "open";
    }

    // get an item from the path
    IShellItem item;
    int hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(parsingPath, IntPtr.Zero, typeof(IShellItem).GUID, out item);
    if (hr < 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(hr);

    // get the context menu from the item
    IContextMenu menu;
    Guid BHID_SFUIObject = new Guid("{3981e225-f559-11d3-8e3a-00c04f6837d5}");
    hr = item.BindToHandler(IntPtr.Zero, BHID_SFUIObject, typeof(IContextMenu).GUID, out menu);
    if (hr < 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(hr);

    // build a fake context menu so we can scan it for the verb's menu id
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    hr = menu.QueryContextMenu(cm.Handle, 0, 0, -1, CMF_NORMAL);
    if (hr < 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(hr);

    int count = GetMenuItemCount(cm.Handle);
    int verbId = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int id = GetMenuItemID(cm.Handle, i);
        if (id < 0)
            continue;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
        hr = menu.GetCommandString(id, GCS_VERBW, IntPtr.Zero, sb, sb.Capacity);
        if (sb.ToString() == verb)
        {
            verbId = id;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (verbId < 0)
        throw new Win32Exception("Verb '" + verb + "' is not supported by the item");

    // call that verb
    CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO ci = new CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO();
    ci.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO));
    ci.lpVerb  = (IntPtr)verbId;
    hr = menu.InvokeCommand(ref ci);
    if (hr < 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(hr);
}

[ComImport, Guid("43826D1E-E718-42EE-BC55-A1E261C37BFE"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
private interface IShellItem
{
    // NOTE: only partially defined, don't use in other contexts
    [PreserveSig]
    int BindToHandler(IntPtr pbc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid bhid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, out IContextMenu ppv);
}

[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("000214e4-0000-0000-c000-000000000046")]
private interface IContextMenu
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryContextMenu(IntPtr hmenu, int iMenu, int idCmdFirst, int idCmdLast, int uFlags); 

    [PreserveSig]
    int InvokeCommand(ref CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO pici);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetCommandString(int idCmd, int uFlags, IntPtr pwReserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszName, int cchMax);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hMenu);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetMenuItemID(IntPtr hMenu, int nPos);

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SHCreateItemFromParsingName(string path, IntPtr pbc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, out IShellItem item);

private const int CMF_NORMAL = 0x00000000;
private const int GCS_VERBW = 4;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private struct CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public int fMask;
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public IntPtr lpVerb;
    public string lpParameters;
    public string lpDirectory;
    public int nShow;
    public int dwHotKey;
    public IntPtr hIcon;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, it's a really good solution for generic usage, but knowing the alternatives I preffer to use the Shell32 in-1-line solution to invoke a verb using a native method than hardcoding a 400 line solution (I've included in the sum the required XML documentation) with GUIDS that can change or anything else where I could have problems such as ANSI-UNICODE verb parsing (I don't know if that can give me a problem)... sorry but I'm looking for the way to do it using WindowsAPICodePack. Just to notice: The IShellItem interface is included in WindowsAPICodePack. Thanks again!

Comment: There's nothing "hardcoded" here. These guids will *never* change. You should not have any problem with unicode unless you work with an old Windows 95. And I don't think you can do it with the Windows API Code pack only because it has zero notion of IContextMenu. I know IShellItem is included but its defined as internal. They don't even provide a way to get to the underlying IShellItem of the ShellObject as it's marked as private...

Comment: It's ok thanks for the clarifications in that case I mark the answer as accepted. PS: forgive my bad English. just one thing that I have unclear is if I try to use the `open` verb with the `CallShellItemVerb` it throws the exception that says `verb is not supported by the item`, but if I use the same `open` verb using the `invokeverb` method of `shell32 interface` then it works ok and opens the properties of the deleted item on the recycle bin... then why the `open` verb don't works with this code? (I need to use the verb `properties` instead of `open`)

Comment: You can also use the 'undelete' verb using the "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation" object, but would have been another question. Just use InvokeVerb("undelete") on a FolderItem object, got from new Shell().NameSpace(ShellSpecialFolderConstants.ssfBITBUCKET)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an adaptation of @Nathan M solution to work properly with a `ShellObject` object (which can be a `ShellItem` or `ShellFolder` or others).

The `WindowsAPICodePack` library provides a `WindowShowCommand` enumeration used in the `ShellExecuteInfo` structure so there is no need to write documentation for it.

Here is:

```
''' <summary>
''' Performs an operation on a specified file..
''' </summary>
''' <param name="lpExecInfo">
''' A pointer to a 'ShellExecuteInfo' structure that contains and receives information about
''' the application being executed.
''' </param>
''' <returns><c>true</c> if successful, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
<DllImport("Shell32", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function ShellExecuteEx(
              ByRef lpExecInfo As ShellExecuteInfo
) As Boolean
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Contains information used by 'ShellExecuteEx' function.
''' </summary>
<Description("'lpExecInfo' parameter used in 'ShellExecuteEx' function")>
Public Structure ShellExecuteInfo

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Required. 
    ''' The size of this structure, in bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public cbSize As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Flags that indicate the content and validity of the other structure members.
    ''' </summary>
    Public fMask As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Optional. 
    ''' A handle to the parent window, 
    ''' used to display any message boxes that the system might produce while executing this function. 
    ''' This value can be NULL.
    ''' </summary>
    Public hwnd As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A string, referred to as a verb, that specifies the action to be performed. 
    ''' The set of available verbs depends on the particular file or folder. 
    ''' Generally, the actions available from an object's shortcut menu are available verbs. 
    ''' This parameter can be NULL, in which case the default verb is used if available. 
    ''' If not, the "open" verb is used. 
    ''' If neither verb is available, the system uses the first verb listed in the registry. 
    ''' </summary>
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> Public lpVerb As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The address of a null-terminated string that specifies the name of the file 
    ''' or object on which ShellExecuteEx will perform the action specified by the lpVerb parameter. 
    ''' The system registry verbs that are supported by the ShellExecuteEx function include "open" 
    ''' for executable files and document files and "print" for document files 
    ''' for which a print handler has been registered. 
    ''' Other applications might have added Shell verbs through the system registry, 
    ''' such as "play" for .avi and .wav files.
    ''' To specify a Shell namespace object, pass the fully qualified parse name 
    ''' and set the SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST flag in the fMask parameter.
    ''' </summary>
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> Public lpFile As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Optional. 
    ''' The address of a null-terminated string that contains the application parameters. 
    ''' The parameters must be separated by spaces. 
    ''' If the lpFile member specifies a document file, lpParameters should be NULL.
    ''' </summary>
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> Public lpParameters As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Optional. 
    ''' The address of a null-terminated string that specifies the name of the working directory. 
    ''' If this member is NULL, the current directory is used as the working directory.
    ''' </summary>
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> Public lpDirectory As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Required. 
    ''' Flags that specify how an application is to be shown when it is opened; 
    ''' one of the SW_ values listed for the ShellExecute function. 
    ''' If lpFile specifies a document file, the flag is simply passed to the associated application. 
    ''' It is up to the application to decide how to handle it.
    ''' </summary>
    Dim nShow As WindowShowCommand

    ''' <summary>
    ''' If SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS is set and the ShellExecuteEx call succeeds, 
    ''' it sets this member to a value greater than 32. 
    ''' If the function fails, it is set to an SE_ERR_XXX error value that indicates the cause of the failure. 
    ''' Although hInstApp is declared as an HINSTANCE for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications, 
    ''' it is not a true HINSTANCE. 
    ''' It can be cast only to an int and compared to either 32 or the following SE_ERR_XXX error codes.
    ''' </summary>
    Dim hInstApp As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The address of an absolute ITEMIDLIST structure (PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE) 
    ''' to contain an item identifier list that uniquely identifies the file to execute. 
    ''' This member is ignored if the fMask member does not include SEE_MASK_IDLIST or SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST.
    ''' </summary>
    Dim lpIDList As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The address of a null-terminated string that specifies one of the following
    ''' A ProgId. For example, "Paint.Picture".
    ''' A URI protocol scheme. For example, "http".
    ''' A file extension. For example, ".txt".
    ''' A registry path under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT that names a subkey that contains one or more Shell verbs. 
    ''' This key will have a subkey that conforms to the Shell verb registry schema, such as shell\verb name.
    ''' </summary>
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> Public lpClass As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A handle to the registry key for the file type. 
    ''' The access rights for this registry key should be set to KEY_READ. 
    ''' This member is ignored if fMask does not include SEE_MASK_CLASSKEY.
    ''' </summary>
    Public hkeyClass As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A keyboard shortcut to associate with the application. 
    ''' The low-order word is the virtual key code, and the high-order word is a modifier flag (HOTKEYF_).
    ''' For a list of modifier flags, see the description of the WM_SETHOTKEY message. 
    ''' This member is ignored if fMask does not include SEE_MASK_HOTKEY.
    ''' </summary>
    Public dwHotKey As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A handle to the icon for the file type. 
    ''' This member is ignored if fMask does not include SEE_MASK_ICON. 
    ''' This value is used only in Windows XP and earlier. 
    ''' It is ignored as of Windows Vista.
    ''' </summary>
    Public hIcon As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A handle to the monitor upon which the document is to be displayed. 
    ''' This member is ignored if fMask does not include SEE_MASK_HMONITOR.
    ''' </summary>
    Public hProcess As IntPtr

End Structure

''' <summary>
''' Invokes a verb on a ShellObject item.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ShellObject">
''' Indicates the item.
''' </param>
''' <param name="Verb">
''' Indicates the verb to invoke on the item.
''' </param>
Public Shared Sub InvokeItemVerb(ByVal [ShellObject] As ShellObject,
                                 ByVal Verb As String)

    Dim FileName As String = [ShellObject].ParsingName.Split("\").Last
    Dim FileDir As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName([ShellObject].ParsingName)

    Dim sei As New ShellExecuteInfo

    With sei

        .cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(sei)

        ' Here we want ONLY the filename (without the path).
        .lpFile = FileName

        ' Here we want the exact directory from the parsing name.
        .lpDirectory = FileDir

        ' Here the show command.
        .nShow = WindowShowCommand.Show

        ' Here the verb to invoke.
        .lpVerb = Verb

    End With

    ' Invoke the verb.
    ShellExecuteEx(sei)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I still looking for the way to invoke a verb using `Windows API Code Pack`.

This answer is just to share the code of @Simon Mourier translated to VB.NET and added documentation if someone is interested to use this geeneric solution.

Credits to him.

```
''' <summary>
''' Exposes methods that retrieve information about a Shell item. 
''' IShellItem and IShellItem2 are the preferred representations of items in any new code.
''' </summary>
<ComImport, Guid("43826D1E-E718-42EE-BC55-A1E261C37BFE"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Interface IShellItem

    REM NOTE: This interface is only partially defined, don't use it in other contexts.

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Binds to a handler for an item as specified by the handler ID value (BHID).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="pbc">
    ''' A pointer to an IBindCtx interface on a bind context object. 
    ''' Used to pass optional parameters to the handler. 
    ''' The contents of the bind context are handler-specific. 
    ''' For example, when binding to BHID_Stream, the STGM flags in the bind context indicate the 
    ''' mode of access desired (read or read/write).</param>
    ''' <param name="bhid">
    ''' Reference to a GUID that specifies which handler will be created. 
    ''' One of the following values defined in Shlguid.h.</param>
    ''' <param name="riid">
    ''' IID of the object type to retrieve.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="ppv">
    ''' When this method returns, 
    ''' contains a pointer of type riid that is returned by the handler specified by rbhid.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
    <PreserveSig>
    Function BindToHandler(
             ByVal pbc As IntPtr,
             <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal bhid As Guid,
             <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal riid As Guid,
             ByRef ppv As IContextMenu
    ) As Integer
End Interface

''' <summary>
''' Exposes methods that either create or merge a shortcut menu associated with a Shell object.
''' </summary>
<ComImport, Guid("000214e4-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Interface IContextMenu

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds commands to a shortcut menu.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="hmenu">
    ''' A handle to the shortcut menu. 
    ''' The handler should specify this handle when adding menu items.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="iMenu">
    ''' The zero-based position at which to insert the first new menu item.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="idCmdFirst">
    ''' The minimum value that the handler can specify for a menu item identifier.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="idCmdLast">
    ''' The maximum value that the handler can specify for a menu item identifier.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="uFlags">
    ''' Optional flags that specify how the shortcut menu can be changed. 
    ''' The remaining bits of the low-order word are reserved by the system. 
    ''' The high-order word can be used for context-specific communications. 
    ''' The CMF_RESERVED value can be used to mask the low-order word.</param>
    ''' <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
    <PreserveSig>
    Function QueryContextMenu(
             ByVal hmenu As IntPtr,
             ByVal iMenu As Integer,
             ByVal idCmdFirst As Integer,
             ByVal idCmdLast As Integer,
             ByVal uFlags As QueryContextMenuFlags
    ) As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Carries out the command associated with a shortcut menu item.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="pici">
    ''' A pointer to a CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO or CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX structure that contains 
    ''' specifics about the command.</param>
    ''' <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
    <PreserveSig>
    Function InvokeCommand(
             ByRef pici As CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO
    ) As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets information about a shortcut menu command, 
    ''' including the help string and the language-independent, or canonical, name for the command.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="idCmd">
    ''' Menu command identifier offset.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="uFlags">
    ''' Flags specifying the information to return. 
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="pwReserved">
    ''' Reserved. 
    ''' Applications must specify NULL when calling this method and 
    ''' handlers must ignore this parameter when called.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="pszName">
    ''' The address of the buffer to receive the null-terminated string being retrieved.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="cchMax">
    ''' Size of the buffer, in characters, to receive the null-terminated string.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
    <PreserveSig>
    Function GetCommandString(
             ByVal idCmd As Integer,
             ByVal uFlags As GetCommandStringFlags,
             ByVal pwReserved As IntPtr,
             <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszName As StringBuilder,
             ByVal cchMax As Integer) As Integer
End Interface



''' <summary>
''' Determines the number of items in the specified menu.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="hMenu">A handle to the menu to be examined.</param>
''' <returns>
''' If the function succeeds, the return value specifies the number of items in the menu.
''' If the function fails, the return value is -1.</returns>
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function GetMenuItemCount(
              ByVal hMenu As IntPtr
) As Integer
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Retrieves the menu item identifier of a menu item located at the specified position in a menu.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="hMenu">
''' A handle to the menu that contains the item whose identifier is to be retrieved.
''' </param>
''' <param name="nPos">
''' The zero-based relative position of the menu item whose identifier is to be retrieved.
''' </param>
''' <returns>
''' The return value is the identifier of the specified menu item. 
''' If the menu item identifier is NULL or if the specified item opens a submenu, the return value is -1.
''' </returns>
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function GetMenuItemID(
              ByVal hMenu As IntPtr,
              ByVal nPos As Integer
) As Integer
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Creates and initializes a Shell item object from a parsing name.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="path">
''' A pointer to a display name.
''' </param>
''' <param name="pbc">
''' Optional.
''' A pointer to a bind context used to pass parameters as inputs and outputs to the parsing function. 
''' These passed parameters are often specific to the data source and are documented by the data source owners.
''' </param>
''' <param name="riid">
''' A reference to the IID of the interface to retrieve through ppv, 
''' typically IID_IShellItem or IID_IShellItem2.
''' </param>
''' <param name="item">
''' When this method returns successfully, contains the interface pointer requested in riid. 
''' This is typically IShellItem or IShellItem2.</param>
''' <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
<DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function SHCreateItemFromParsingName(
              ByVal path As String,
              ByVal pbc As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)>
              ByVal riid As Guid,
              ByRef item As IShellItem
) As Integer
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Optional flags that specify how a shortcut menu can be changed.
''' </summary>
<Description("'uFlags' parameter used in 'QueryContextMenu' function")>
Public Enum QueryContextMenuFlags As Integer

    REM NOTE: This Enum is only partially defined, don't use it in other contexts. 

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates normal operation. 
    ''' A shortcut menu extension, namespace extension, or drag-and-drop handler can add all menu items.
    ''' </summary>
    CMF_NORMAL = &H0

End Enum

''' <summary>
''' Flags specifying the information to return.
''' </summary>
<Description("'uFlags' parameter used in 'GetCommandString' function")>
Public Enum GetCommandStringFlags As Integer

    REM NOTE: This Enum is only partially defined, don't use it in other contexts. 

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets pszName to a Unicode string containing the language-independent command name for the menu item.
    ''' </summary>
    GCS_VERBW = &H4

End Enum

''' <summary>
''' Contains information needed by IContextMenu::InvokeCommand to invoke a shortcut menu command.
''' </summary>
<Description("'pici' parameter used in 'InvokeCommand' function")>
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Structure CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The size of this structure, in bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public cbSize As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Zero, or one or more of the CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO flags.
    ''' </summary>
    Public fMask As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A handle to the window that is the owner of the shortcut menu.
    ''' An extension can also use this handle as the owner of any message boxes or dialog boxes it displays.
    ''' </summary>
    Public hwnd As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The address of a null-terminated string that specifies the language-independent name 
    ''' of the command to carry out. 
    ''' This member is typically a string when a command is being activated by an application. 
    ''' The system provides predefined constant values for the following command strings.
    ''' </summary>
    Public lpVerb As IntPtr

    ''' <summary>
    ''' An optional string containing parameters that are passed to the command. 
    ''' The format of this string is determined by the command that is to be invoked. 
    ''' This member is always NULL for menu items inserted by a Shell extension.
    ''' </summary>
    Public lpParameters As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' An optional working directory name. 
    ''' This member is always NULL for menu items inserted by a Shell extension.
    ''' </summary>
    Public lpDirectory As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A set of SW_ values to pass to the ShowWindow function if the command 
    ''' displays a window or starts an application.
    ''' </summary>
    Public nShow As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' An optional keyboard shortcut to assign to any application activated by the command. 
    ''' If the fMask parameter does not specify CMIC_MASK_HOTKEY, this member is ignored.
    ''' </summary>
    Public dwHotKey As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' An icon to use for any application activated by the command. 
    ''' If the fMask member does not specify CMIC_MASK_ICON, this member is ignored.
    ''' </summary>
    Public hIcon As IntPtr

End Structure

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Invokes a verb on a ShellObject item.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="ShellObject">
    ''' Indicates the item.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="Verb">
    ''' Indicates the verb to invoke on the item.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">ParsingPath</exception>
    ''' <exception cref="System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception">
    ''' </exception>
    Public Shared Sub InvokeItemVerb(ByVal [ShellObject] As ShellObject,
                                     ByVal Verb As String)

        Dim [ShellItem] As NativeMethods.IShellItem = Nothing
        Dim menu As NativeMethods.IContextMenu = Nothing
        Dim ci As New NativeMethods.CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO
        Dim cm As New ContextMenu
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(256)
        Dim hr As Integer = -1
        Dim count As Integer = -1
        Dim verbId As Integer = -1
        Dim id As Integer = -1
        Dim BHID_SFUIObject As Guid = Nothing

        If Verb Is Nothing Then
            Verb = "open"
        End If

        ' Get an item from the item parsing-path
        hr = NativeMethods.SHCreateItemFromParsingName([ShellObject].Properties.System.ParsingPath.Value,
                                                       IntPtr.Zero,
                                                       GetType(NativeMethods.IShellItem).GUID,
                                                       [ShellItem])

        If hr < 0 Then
            Throw New Win32Exception(hr)
        End If

        ' Get the context menu from the item
        BHID_SFUIObject = New Guid("{3981e225-f559-11d3-8e3a-00c04f6837d5}")
        hr = [ShellItem].BindToHandler(IntPtr.Zero, BHID_SFUIObject,
                                       GetType(NativeMethods.IContextMenu).GUID,
                                       menu)

        If hr < 0 Then
            Throw New Win32Exception(hr)
        End If

        ' Build a fake context menu so we can scan it for the verb's menu id.
        hr = menu.QueryContextMenu(cm.Handle, 0, 0, -1,
                                   NativeMethods.QueryContextMenuFlags.CMF_NORMAL)

        If hr < 0 Then
            Throw New Win32Exception(hr)
        End If

        count = NativeMethods.GetMenuItemCount(cm.Handle)

        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1

            id = NativeMethods.GetMenuItemID(cm.Handle, i)

            If id < 0 Then
                Continue For
            End If

            hr = menu.GetCommandString(id, NativeMethods.GetCommandStringFlags.GCS_VERBW,
                                       IntPtr.Zero, sb, sb.Capacity)

            If sb.ToString().Equals(Verb, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                verbId = id
                Exit For
            End If

        Next i

        If verbId < 0 Then
            Throw New Win32Exception(String.Format("Verb '{0}' is not supported by the item.", Verb))
        End If

        ' Invoke the Verb.
        With ci
            .cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(NativeMethods.CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO))
            .lpVerb = New IntPtr(verbId)
        End With

        hr = menu.InvokeCommand(ci)

        If hr < 0 Then
            Throw New Win32Exception(hr)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: @Nathan M Really more than a problem with the code is an aestheticism problem, I've avoided/replaced the usage of Shell32 interface to get inside the recycle bin via WindowsAPiCodePack methods, then now I don't would like to use a 200-lines solution if this can be done  with an non-documented method inside the WindowsAPICodePack library, but by the moment I don't know the way to invoke a verb using WindowsAPICodePack.

Comment: I did it by changing the Windows API Code Pack, and recompiling it. :-)  Actually, not too long ago I ran into a crap ton of issues trying to actually pull up the actual shell popup menu, but IContextMenu2 and IContextMenu3 won't fire correctly from a WndProc that is marshaled into managed code so I wrote a small C++/CLI library to handle some of the more delicate shell functions I might need.

As for invoking the verb, you should be able to use ShellExecuteEx(). Have you not tried that?

Comment: @Nathan M nope I didn't knew that api method, I've searched the definitios on pinvoke.net site to test this api and I've parsed the parsingname of a deleted file to open the `properties` dialog, the difference using `ShellExecuteEx` is that I get the normal properties dialog (there is not a `restore file` option which is present in the recycled file properties dialog) then also I can't use the `undelete` verb 'cause it says that doesn't exist any program associated with that verb. maybe I'm doing something bad in the Structure parameters that I use for the function.

Comment: My structure members looks like this: `sei.lpVerb = "undelete" : sei.lpFile = file.ParsingName : sei.nShow = SW_SHOW : sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST` could you say me if the constants are right? then why I can't use it correctly with a deleted file?

Comment: Set the lpDirectory structure variable = "::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}"

Comment: @Nathan M I understand what you've said to use the clsid of the recycle bin virtual directory, I did the modification but I still can't see the right file property dialog also I still can't undelete an item

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45583/discussion-between-nathan-m-and-elektrostudios)

Answer (score 0):

I had success with this

```
Public Function RestoreFromBin(originalFilePath As String)
    Dim fileItem = WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.KnownFolders.RecycleBin.FirstOrDefault(Function(so) so.Name = originalFilePath)
    If fileItem IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim shex As New SHELLEXECUTEINFO() With {.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(shex), .lpFile = IO.Path.GetFileName(fileItem.ParsingName), .lpDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileItem.ParsingName), .nShow = 5, .lpVerb = "undelete"}
        Return ShellExecuteEx(shex)
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```